# Redirecting to specific page on 404 errors if url contains a string in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying redirect to a specific page (store page) if a user tries to access a page with a url that contains "/product/" as well as gets a 404 error.

This is what I currently have in my htaccess:

RewriteRule ^/product/.* /store [R=404,L]

What do I need to change to get this working?

Here my current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Send surplus store 404 errors to the store home page
ErrorDocument 404 /store
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?product(/.*)?$ - [R=404,L,NC]

# handle both specific URL redirects for woocommerce
RewriteRule ^/?product-(?:tag|categories|category)/([\w-]+) www.mydomain.com/parts?category=$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^MyAccount\.aspx\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/online\.mydomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your site root .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# handle both specific URL redirects for woocommerce
RewriteRule ^/?product-(?:tag|categories|category)/([\w-]+) www.mydomain.com/parts?category=$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^MyAccount\.aspx(/.*)?$ http://online.mydomain.com$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]

# redirect /product URIs
RewriteRule ^/?product(/.*)?$ /store [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it is not working on my end with this url www.mydomain.com/product/t414751r-exchdpf-filter

Comment: ok, i have updated the question with my htaccess i had to remove some of the https://

Comment: Ah this is wordpress :( You will have to do it differently via theme's 404 handler and may be WP rewrite API

Comment: Or if you are fine with full redirect to `/store` with `301/302` then we can do it via `RewriteRule`

Comment: Ya, unfortunately this is wordpress. I think I would be fine with it redirecting with 301/302

Comment: ok replace your .htaccess with what I have in m answer and retest after clearing browser cache.